# Why isn't my whole LineairLayout showing?

Tags: android, xml, dialog, android-linearlayout

I'm making an Custom Dialog. I have 2 buttons, "Select Other Cards" and "Ok" but somehow the "Ok" button won't show. I'm quite new using LineairLayouts. I have a horizontal layout in an vertical one.

What the dialog shows:

[image]

What I want the dialog to show:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorLightBlue"
    android:onClick="selectOtherCardsButtonClick">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/finishedTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/patrickhand_regular"
        android:text="@string/finishedCards"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/selectOtherButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/selectOtherButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:text="@string/selectOtherCards"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/okButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/selectOtherButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope anyone knows what my problem is.

Thankyou for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `selectOtherButton` covers all the horizontal space and the `okButton` is under `selectOtherButton`.

Define weights for the space that will cover each button, something like 4 to 1 (or adjust it to suit your design) with the `android:layout_weight` attribute for both buttons:

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/selectOtherButton"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:text="@string/selectOtherCards"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/okButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/selectOtherButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to lower your text size for example try with:

`android:textSize="14sp"`

or use less words like: `select others`. Weight might convert the button to two rows. And it might not look good in the end.